# Winamp control on windows lock screen?

Tags: windows, winamp

Is there a way to control winamp in the windows lock screen?

When i press the play / pause button on my multimedia keyboard it control winamp, but not when the computer is locked.

Comment: I can't definitively answer the question one way or the other, but I would expect this to be something of a security issue.

Comment: but muting or changing volume works on lock screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the answer would be **no.** When your session is locked, the lock screen is displayed on a separate desktop, to prevent *any* possible information leaks or meddling with the running programs.

(The volume controls work because they are managed by Windows itself (probaby Winlogon). You might have noticed that they keep working when Winamp is closed.)

---

It *is* possible to run other programs in the secure desktop: `psexec -dix someprogram.exe`. So if you manage to find (or write) a Winamp remote-control program, you could run it this way... (But then, what happens if said remote-control program allows browsing files or the like? All security of screen locking goes poof.)

Comment: what if i run winamp using psexec?

Comment: @bortao: It will appear on the lock screen... But *only* on the lock screen, and will be inaccessible from the normal desktop. Also, you will be introducing a huge security hole: anyone can browse files and even run programs by using Winamp's "Open file" dialogs, essentially bypassing the screenlock.

Comment: i dont think one could write a remote control though... it would involve accessing a process of another user.. dunno if that's possible? maybe only if you run both winamp and the remote control on the SYSTEM user. well anyway.. i think the answer is better as "no, you cant control" :)

Comment: @bortao: Another user? No, you could just run it under your own account (using psexec). And either way, there are several methods of IPC that do not involve accessing the process directly, such as named pipes or TCP/IP, with the other end being a Winamp plugin or a simple window-message sender.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing an option to auto stop song when Windows Session is locked, so I've let available a simple plugin to do this at http://www.vextenso.com.br/blog/126/winamp-plugin-lock-session-detection-lsd.html